# Concurrent dependant routines in a gui application

Tags: c++, c++17, concurrency, gui, qt

The idea is that, in my application I have 5 routines named `long_process_1`, `long_process_2`, `long_process_3`, `long_process_4`, `long_process_5`. These are each long calculations that would hang the GUI and can only be called in that order. When each result is ready, user input is required about the result. So we call `ask_user_1`, `ask_user_2`, `ask_user_3`, `ask_user_4`, `ask_user_5` which must obviously run in the main GUI thread. Thus the whole thing cannot be run in a separate thread in its entirety. Here's how I did it:

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_button_click() // starts with a button click
{
    QEventLoop eventLoop;
    QFutureWatcher<int> watch;

    // Watcher intercepts eventLoop when the computation is finished
    connect(&watch, &decltype(watch)::finished, &eventLoop, &decltype(eventLoop)::quit);

    auto const res1 = QtConcurrent::run(long_process_1);
    watch.setFuture(res1);
    eventLoop.exec(); // Handles GUI during computation
    auto const user_in1 = ask_user_1(res1);

    auto const res2 = QtConcurrent::run(long_process_2, user_in1);
    watch.setFuture(res2);
    eventLoop.exec();
    auto const user_in2 = ask_user_2(res2);

    auto const res3 = QtConcurrent::run(long_process_3, user_in2);
    watch.setFuture(res3);
    eventLoop.exec();
    auto const user_in3 = ask_user_3(res3);

    auto const res4 = QtConcurrent::run(long_process_4, user_in3);
    watch.setFuture(res4);
    eventLoop.exec();
    auto const user_in4 = ask_user_4(res4);

    auto res5 = QtConcurrent::run(long_process_5, user_in4);
    watch.setFuture(res5);
    eventLoop.exec();
    (void)ask_user_5(res5); // result is not used
}
```

This works alright. I find this a lot simpler than running the whole thing through "on-finished" signal-slots. It also simplifies ownership of local variables/function results as they are all in a single function. The long routines are clearly decoupled from the function calling them. It seems a bit odd overall though. I got the idea from very old Qt [docs](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq27-responsive-guis.html). All comments are welcome.

#### Edit:

Coroutines might be helpful. They are not supported in Qt yet, but [this](https://github.com/danvratil/qcoro) library is worth looking into.

Comment: Those are terrible variable names - they should really reflect the actions, rather than the sequencing (and that will save you from pain when you realise you need a step between 3a and 3b....)

Comment: @TobySpeight this is an implementation of the *idea*. Within this context, the variable names make sense. Is it worth closing this question over variable names?

Comment: It looks like example/obfuscated code.  I'd like to be able to answer, but there really isn't very much reviewable here, especially since your  `long_process_x` variables and `ask_user_x` functions are completely missing.

Comment: @TobySpeight I want the function design to be reviewed. Would you say that is off-topic on this website? I can delete this 2-years-old question if it is.

Comment: Consensus here is that we don't review design in the abstract.  I understand the question is old (I will have missed it when I was offline due to Covid restrictions; otherwise I would probably have picked this up when it was new).  I don't think you'll be allowed to delete it because it has an upvoted answer, so I've asked the community to decide whether it belongs.

Comment: This question is currently being discussed in the [2nd Monitor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

Comment: "Is it worth closing this question over variable names" It's not just the variable names. I think [this answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2316/52915) explains it pretty well. "You cannot change the design without heavily impacting the code." We can take a look at the design as part of the rest of the code, but without sufficient code there's nothing to look at. Based on what you currently show us, I'd say it's a poor design. Part of that could be fixed with additional functions or using a container type, but I can't say for sure without seeing what it's doing at the moment.

Comment: Also see the [help/on-topic] (on-topic), [help/dont-ask] (don't ask) and [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/52915).

Comment: Based on the discussion in the 2nd Monitor and the cited Meta post I am voting to close this question.

Comment: @Mast I don't quite understand what critical context you are missing here. You can imagine that the `long_process_x` functions have the thread sleep for 10 seconds and return `0` and you can imagine the `ask_user_x` functions show the user a dialog and ask if them to "click OK to proceed". If I posted that, people would focus on that filler code and the actual question would be lost in noise. Do you really expect me to post the source code of a full GUI application? With the XML UI files? That would be hundreds of lines of code so people can review this one function?

Answer (score 2):

Running non-gui related stuffs using the main event-dispatch(gui-thread) is kind of anti-gui practice.

If first process should be called, and then second process, so it's basically a long synchronous calls (with user prompt between each)

Probably(good practice) is run the first long process using a thread(usually out of event-dispatch/gui-thread).

Meanwhile, the long process could inform the GUI about the process by sending progress events(assuming gui works as a process-progress-listener here).

Now, because the long process is run by a thread, gui is functional, and not freezing, so user could see progress, or control the progress(e.g. abort, etc...)

Once the long thread is finished, ask the gui-thread/event-dispatch for user prompt, and if starting the second long process is a thing, go for it just like first one using a thread.

**Overall**

Try not to perform excessive non-gui stuffs using gui-thread/event-dispatch. This is actually a good practice.

Try not to perform gui related stuffs(such as updating a progress-bar value/status) using non-gui threads(out of widget/dispatch scope). This may not be valid for all widgets, but usually(possible) any gui change(here like progress-bar change) seems to be ignored.
But actually that out-of-scope thread could not force the main-gui thread to perform a refresh/repaint on target component.

Assuming, the-gui/event-dispatch thread is the guy who sitting next to the widget door, and is waiting for any gui-related requests.
So if a request about updating progress-bar is made *correctly* by the expected routine, that guy will repaint the target progress-bar since it have to.

But what happens when the request came from out of event-dispatch scope? It's more like getting into the room from windows, rather the door, and the guy next to it.
So technically progress bar will be updated, but might not updated immediately(or at all), since the guy who in charge to keeps ui updated did not realized there is a requests that forces component(s) to get repainted.

Comment: I am not sure what I am doing is excessively non-gui in gui thread though. All non-gui stuff are done in other threads. Gui thread simply handles the user-interaction part. Otherwise it gets way too complicated. The gui thread creates a worker thread. This thread returns back with the answer, but can't prompt the user, so somehow has to go ask the gui thread to do it. Gui thread must call a different function which does the second thread creation, which must also do the same thing. Then a third function and so on and so on.

Comment: Could you in a small sample show how you would propose this to be done?

Comment: Not every widget come with same/one threading/dispatching impl. But certainly there must a way in your case to allow the worker non-gui thread callback a gui routine when it's done, lets see what QT provide for that then? ([this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-threads-waitconditions-example.html) may help)